# Center of a tree node in D3.js v6

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tree

I'm trying to center a given node after it has been clicked, just like it's done in [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/Tokker/mwm1sxhh/21/). However, in the example it's done in D3 v4, and I want to do it in the latest version (v6). The main problem is that I don't understand how `centerNode()` function works (i.e. how it's obtaining the coordinates of x and y and what it's doing with them), so that I can't change it myself. Can someone help me understand what it's doing, and give some hints on what are the changes that need to be made?

P.S. If someone thinks it's better to share some parts of my code just let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SVG zooms and moves its contents, using 3 parameters (zoomX, zoomY, zoomK), where zoomX and zoomY are vertical / horizontal shift and zoomK is the scaling factor. Thus every node having coordinates nodeX, nodeY will be positioned using the following transform:

```
actualX = nodeX * zoomK + zoomX;
actualY = nodeY * zoomK + zoomY;
```

To move the selected node exactly to the center of the SCG element, its actual coordinates should be:

```
centerX = viewerWidth / 2;
centerY = viewerHeight / 2;
```

Therefore, we calculate zoomX / zoomY the following way:

```
zoomX = -nodeX * zoomK + centerX;
zoomY = -nodeY * zoomK + centerY;
```

Now, SVG can move its contents using the zoom transform:

```
zoomK = t.k
zoomX = -nodeX * zoomK + centerX;
zoomY = -nodeY * zoomK + centerY;  
identity = d3.zoomIdentity.translate(zoomX,zoomY).scale(zoomK)  
svg
  .transition()
  .duration(time)
  .call(zoomListener.transform, identity);
```